# Run a function between two inputs in the console

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a Script that works well, but I would like to add an implementation to it.
In first place, I am using the Script to communicate with a couple of devices (Frequency generator and Oscilloscope) via PyVISA and get some measurements. At a certain step during the process, I have to adjust manually a Photodetector (physical device that cannot be used with PyVISA, but attached to the oscilloscope) with a knob which is very sensitive and can be damaged. I am using my own function to control the damage measuring the voltage through the oscilloscope, named PreventAPD. Mainly the function reads the voltage of the oscilloscope and if it is larger than a certain level it stops the system.

When running the script, there is a moment when a message is shown in the console to proceed to the adjustment, I want at this moment to start running the  PreventAPD function and that it stops running when the adjustment is done and I push Enter in the console again. The adjustment time can take uncertian times, sometimes 1 min or maybe 3 mins.

The code below shows an example of my question.

```
print('Adjust manually the Gain from the APD')
input('Press Enter to continue')               <---- From here
PreventAPD()                                   <---- Function to run
PreventLD()                                    <---- Function to run
M = int(input("Insert the value of M: "))
print(f"The value of M is {M}")
input('Press Enter to continue')               <---- Until here
```

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Try to rephrase your question. It doesn't make sense now. How does it work now? How would you like it to work after the changes? What are you adjusting manually? What do you mean by "I would like them to be run during 2 inputs in the python console"?

Comment: your script already run functions between 2 inputs, 1st input is "enter to continue" so if you don't press enter, it will halt, after enter, your script then run 2 functions, and then wait for another input

Comment: @am05mhz thanks for your reply. Yes, the script runs the functions between the two inputs in the console, but just once. Adjusting manually can take for example 1 min, and the time elapsed for the function can be like 3 seconds, so I would like it to be running in a loop that starts with an input console and stops with another input console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> … the script runs the functions between the two inputs in the console, but just once. … I would like it to be running in a loop that starts with an input console and stops with another input console.

You could use a `KeyboardInterrupt` exception to break a loop:

```
print('Adjust manually the Gain from the APD')
input('Press Enter to continue')
print('Press Interrupt (Ctrl-C) to enter M')
try:
    while True:
        PreventAPD()
        PreventLD()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
M = int(input("Insert the value of M: "))
```